# Problema con Javascript clásico

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy refrescando mis conocimientos de Javascript, para lo cual he creado una sencilla aplicación en la que tengo una caja de texto y dos botones: uno para agregar otra caja de texto y otro para borrarla.

La idea es simular que pedimos al usuario que teclee aficiones y, si así lo desea, pueda borrar alguna de ellas. Bueno, la parte de añadir me la hace sin problemas, la pega viene cuando quiero borrar.

Si bien me deja eliminar el primer elemento, los siguientes no me deja hacerlo, se produce un error en el que me indica que el evento que le paso con el botón borrar es undefined.

Este es el código que tengo. Como veréis es muy sencillo, no tiene mucha complicación, pero falla:

```js
let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

function nueva(){
    //Añade una nueva afición en blanco
    let nodoDiv = document.createElement("div");  
    nodoDiv.classList.add("row", "mt-2");
    nodoDiv.innerHTML = `
    <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                    onclick="nueva()">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                    onclick="borrar()">-</button>
    </div>
    `;
    formulario.appendChild(nodoDiv);
}

function borrar(evento){
    //Añade una nueva afición en blanc
    console.log("evento",evento);
    let boton = evento.target;   
    let elementoBorrar = elemento.parentElement.parentElement; //Row
    formulario.removeChild(elementoBorrar)   
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Demo Javascript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Jugando con Javascript cl&aacute;sico</h1>
        <hr>

        <p class="lead">Introduzca sus aficiones:</p>
        <form class="mt-3" id="formulario">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                        onclick="nueva()">+</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                        onclick="borrar(event)">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Resto de dependencias js para Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Scripts js personalizados -->
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Se os ocurre qué puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 2):

No es conveniente incluir eventos directamente en las etiquetas HTML, puede complicar un poco el funcionamiento, depuración y mantenimiento; lo adecuado es escuchar los eventos y, como los botones son dinámicos, hay que delegarlos.

En este caso, será el formulario el que "escuche" los clics y, si se trata de un botón eliminar, llamar a la función enviando el botón.

Para obtener el padre, no es necesario `.parentNode.parentNode`, puedes llegar más rápido con [`elemento.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) y puedes eliminar directamente con [`elemento.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```js
let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

// Delegar evento, para aplicar a botones aunque no existan todavía
formulario.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Si el clic fue en un botón eliminar (con clase "btn-danger")
    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-danger')) {
        // Ejecutar función enviando botón
        borrar(e.target);
    }
});
function nueva(){
    //Añade una nueva afición en blanco
    let nodoDiv = document.createElement("div");  
    nodoDiv.classList.add("row", "mt-2");
    nodoDiv.innerHTML = `
    <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                    onclick="nueva()">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
    </div>
    `;
    formulario.appendChild(nodoDiv);
}

function borrar(btn){
    // Desde el botón se obtiene el padre por su clase
    let elemBorrar = btn.closest('.row');
    // Eliminar fila
    elemBorrar.remove();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Demo Javascript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Jugando con Javascript cl&aacute;sico</h1>
        <hr>

        <p class="lead">Introduzca sus aficiones:</p>
        <form class="mt-3" id="formulario">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                        onclick="nueva()">+</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Resto de dependencias js para Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Scripts js personalizados -->
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

El código está comentado, pero pregunta si tienes dudas.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el evento, simplemente pasa el objeto `this` asi:

```js
let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

function nueva(){
    //Añade una nueva afición en blanco
    let nodoDiv = document.createElement("div");  
    nodoDiv.classList.add("row", "mt-2");
    nodoDiv.innerHTML = `
    <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                    onclick="nueva()">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                    onclick="borrar(this)">-</button>
    </div>
    `;
    formulario.appendChild(nodoDiv);
}

function borrar(boton){
    //Añade una nueva afición en blanc
     
    let elementoBorrar = boton.parentElement.parentElement; //Row
    formulario.removeChild(elementoBorrar)   
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Demo Javascript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Jugando con Javascript cl&aacute;sico</h1>
        <hr>

        <p class="lead">Introduzca sus aficiones:</p>
        <form class="mt-3" id="formulario">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="teclee un hobbie">
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                        onclick="nueva()">+</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                        onclick="borrar(event)">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Resto de dependencias js para Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Scripts js personalizados -->
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El snippet tiene un error, también intenté sacarlo con `this` pero esta trayendo el selector, no un objeto.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob, ese error es porque quedó `borrar(event)` en el HTML, solo hay que cambiar por `borrar(this)`